# Repeater lista apenas 1 item no IIS

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis

Tenho uma tabela com `Repeater` que lista os itens normalmente, porém quando publico no IIS, só lista 1 item. Será algum problema no IIS? Pois o código está funcionando 100%.

Comment: Será que você não está apontando para um banco diferente e está trazendo somente um item?

Comment: Tem como  colocar o código, provavelmente o banco é diferente